# I cant get Rails5.2 to compile Vue.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpacker

I am trying to compile *.vue files with webpacker so it works in rails.

The project is vue frontend (SPA) with a rails backend but I keep getting the same error.

> Error: [VueLoaderPlugin Error] No matching rule for .vue files found. 
>   │ 18   }, Make sure there is at least one root-level rule that matches
>   .vue or .vue.html files.

I tried to put a rule in my config/webpack/environment.js

Here is the link to the project on github.

https://github.com/ajn123/Ta-Da-List

Comment: It look like you have this working. What was your solution. I'll add an answer with mine.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue. I'm running Rails v5.2.3. I fixed it by using the following `evironment.js` and `vue.js` files:

```
// config/webpacker/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const VueLoaderConfig = require('./loaders/vue')

environment.loaders.append('VueLoaderConfig', VueLoaderConfig)
environment.plugins.append('VueLoaderPlugin', new VueLoaderPlugin())

module.exports = environment
```

```
// config/webpacker/loaders/vue.js

const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')

module.exports = {
  test: /\.vue(\.erb|\.slim)?$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: 'vue-loader',
}
```